# Shopware 6.5: Key provided is shorter than 2048 bits, only 1024 bits provided

Tags: shopware6

The login to the admin does not work after a new installation of shopware 6.5. After entering correct username and passwor, the following error appears in the console: Key provided is shorter than 2048 bits, only 1024 bits provided

Tested on a standard environment at Mittwald: PHP 8.5 and MySQL 8.0.25-15 - installation via Composer.

Password has already been changed and a new user created - both via console. Still the same error.

See also: https://forum.shopware.com/t/fehler-nach-6-5-installation-key-provided-is-shorter-than-2048-bits-only-1024-bits-provided/98739

Comment: Can you share a stack trace where the error really pops up?

Comment: /api/oauth/token
`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\InvalidKeyProvided: "Key provided is shorter than 2048 bits, only 1024 bits provid
ed" at /html/v6.5.0.0/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php line 39 {"exception":"[object] (Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\InvalidKeyProvided(code: 0): Key provided is sh
orter than 2048 bits, only 1024 bits provided at /html/v6.5.0.0/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php:39)"} []`

Comment: Can you try clearing the `config/jwt` directory and running `bin/console system:generate-jwt-secret` again? Not sure why keys with an invalid length are generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the openssl config default config on that system is configured to use a default key_length of 1024 bits.

As a workaround you can change that system wide default value to 2048 bits and run the `bin/console system:generate-jwt-secret --force` command.

We will fix the generation to always generate a key with a valid length independent of the system wide openssl configuration for the final 6.5 version.

Comment: updated to 6.5 and have been hit by this error. did it not make it into the final version?

Comment: This commit should have fixed it and that is included in 6.5.0.0: https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/a50096b2edad04e62fc11e8c2c1301a6010f0112